# Error resolving thymeleaf template when replacing fragment

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have simple SpringBoot application. Everything works fine, but when I try to get *index.html*, where I replaced fragment as shown below, I get an exception:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "~{layout", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (index:2)

Here is my code:

build.gradle generated by [SPRING INITIALIZR](https://start.spring.io/) :

```
buildscript {
        ext {
            springBootVersion = '1.5.7.RELEASE'
        }
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.bearcave'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
}
```

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MessengerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MessengerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:replace="~{layout :: layout (~{::body})}">
<body>
    <div><p>Hello world!</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

layout:

```
<!doctype html>
<html th:fragment="layout (template)" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Messenger</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div th:replace="${template}"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As far as I know, Spring Boot configures itself automatically, default path for .html pages is resources/templates and so I have. Furthermore, there is no problem when I don't try to replace fragment ( I receive simple page with "Hello world!" text).

What I can do to make it work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` uses Thymeleaf **2.1**. In your templates you are using the fragment expression (`~{}`) which was introduced in Thymeleaf **3.0**. That's why your expression isn't parsed as expected and lead to an error.

You have to upgrade your Thymeleaf's dependency to newer version. [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-thymeleaf-3) says how to do this in projects managed by Maven. I'm not familiar with Gradle but I think it's gonna be analogue. According to [this entry](https://medium.com/@dmarko484/spring-boot-spring-boot-1-4-x-thymeleaf-3-x-configuration-b920b1d92ba0), all you have to do is to provide following lines in your **build.gradle** file:

```
ext["thymeleaf.version"] = "3.0.2.RELEASE"
ext["thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version"] = "2.1.1"
```

After that please remove duplicated `xmlns:th` attribute from your **layout** file  (you've provided it twice within `html` tag).

This should resolve your problem.